# Time and space complexity of vector dot-product computation

Tags: algorithm, vector, complexity-theory

What is the time and space complexity of an algorithm, which calculates the dot product between two vectors with the length n?

Comment: What your teacher is probing for is that a dot product is a linear time `O(n)` operation where n is the length of both vectors. This assumes you consider multiplication and addition as constant time operations. Technically `*` and `+` are not constant time. If you want to split hairs and be super precise with the Turing machine time complexity, then define `m` as the average length of the numbers being multiplied and `a` as the average length of the numbers being added. The complexity becomes: `O(n * (m ^ 1.465) + ((n-1) * log(a)))` which collapses to: `O(n*m + n*log(a))`.

Answer (score 18):

If the 2 vectors are `a = [a1, a2, ... , an]` and `b = [b1, b2, ... , bn]`, then

The dot-product is given by     `a.b = a1 * b1 + a2 * b2 + ... + an * bn`

To compute this, we must perform `n` multiplications and `(n-1)` additions. (I assume that this is the dot-product algorithm you are referring to).

Assuming that multiplication and addition are constant-time operations, 
the time-complexity is therefore `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`.

The only auxiliary space we require during the computation is to hold the 'partial dot-product so far' and the last product computed, i.e. `ai * bi`.

Assuming we can hold both values in constant-space, 
the space complexity is therefore `O(1) + O(1) = O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to have it expresses with n. So the time complexity will be n+(n-1) and the space 2n?

Comment: big-theta hides constants too (in this case, O = big-Theta). You mean perhaps an *equivalent*.

Comment: @Alexandre C: I agree - In this case, I have provided Big Theta. Wasn't suggesting that (though reading my comment, that's what it sounds like), just whether the OP was aware that this was actually a tight bound.