# Complexity of a Lucene's search

Tags: lucene, complexity-theory

If I write and algorithm that performs a search using Lucene how can I state the computational complexity of it? I know that Lucene uses tf*idf scoring but I don't know how it is implemented. I've found that tf*idf has the following complexity:

```
O(|D|+|T|)
```

where D is the set of documents and T the set of all terms.

However, I need someone who could check if this is correct and explain me why.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lucene basically uses a `Vector Space Model` (VSM) with a `tf-idf` scheme. So, in the standard setting we have:

- A collection of documents each represented as a vector
- A text query also represented as a vector

We determine the `K` documents of the collection with the highest vector space scores on the query `q`. Typically, we seek these K top documents ordered by score in decreasing order; for instance many search engines use K = 10 to retrieve and rank-order the first page of the ten best results.

The basic algorithm for computing vector space scores is:

```js
float Scores[N] = 0
Initialize Length[N]
for each query term t
do calculate w(t,q) and fetch postings list for t (stored in the index)
    for each pair d,tf(t,d) in postings list
    do Scores[d] += wf(t,d) X w(t,q)  (dot product)
Read the array Length[d]
for each d
do Scored[d] = Scores[d] / Length[d]
return Top K components of Scores[]
```

Where

- The array `Length` holds the lengths (normalization factors) for each of the `N`
  documents, whereas the array `Scores` holds the scores for each of the documents.
- `tf` is the term frequency of a term in a document.
- `w(t,q)` is the weight of the submitted query for a given term. Note that query is treated as a `bag of words` and the vector of weights can be considered (as if it was another document).
- `wf(d,q)` is the logarithmic term weighting for query and document

As described here: [Complexity of vector dot-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744094/time-and-space-complexity-of-vector-dot-product-computation), vector dot-product is `O(n)`. Here the dimension is the number of terms in our vocabulary: `|T|`, where `T` is the set of terms.

So, the time complexity of this algorithm is:

```
O(|Q|· |D| · |T|) = O(|D| · |T|)
```

we consider |Q| fixed, where `Q` is the set of words in the query (which average size is low, in average a query has between 2 and 3 terms) and `D` is the set of all documents.

However, for a search, these sets are bounded and indexes don't tend to grow very often. So, as a result, searches using VSM are really fast (when `T` and `D` are large the search is really slow and one has to find an alternative approach).

Comment: Old answer, but I'm wondering if the complexity changes by using wildcards in the search query? Does handle them differently?

Comment: Great answer! Is there any book or academic reference to this?

Answer (score 0):

> `D` is the set of all documents

before (honestly, along side) VSM, the boolean retrieval is invoked. Thus, we can say `d` is matching docs only (almost. ok. in the best case).
Since `Scores` is priority queue (at least in doc-at-time-scheme) build on heap, putting every `d` into takes `log(K)`. 
Therefore we can estimate it as `O(d·log(K))`, here I omitting `T` since query is expected to be short. (Otherwise, you are in a trouble).

http://www.savar.se/media/1181/space_optimizations_for_total_ranking.pdf