# Bounds of rotations

Tags: python, math

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? It is easy to code this out to work in O(n^2) time complexity where you simply calculate the value of all possible combinations, but I'm unable to come up with an O(n) time complexity solution.

---

Given a list of integers x and a constant c, find the rotations of the list with the highest value and the lowest value respectively, where formula is:

[image]

and weights w = c^i, 0.2 <= c <= 0.8.

For example,

Input:
x = [2,5,6,8]
c = 0.8

Then possible rotations are

- 2 * 0.8**0 + 5 * 0.8**1 + 6 * 0.8**2 + 8 * 0.8**3    <-- Lowest value (13.936)
- 5 * 0.8**0 + 6 * 0.8**1 + 8 * 0.8**2 + 2 * 0.8**3
- 6 * 0.8**0 + 8 * 0.8**1 + 2 * 0.8**2 + 5 * 0.8**3    <-- Highest value (16.24)
- 8 * 0.8**0 + 2 * 0.8**1 + 5 * 0.8**2 + 6 * 0.8**3

Return: (13.936, 16.24)

Solve it in O(n) time complexity.

---

Here's my code:

```
def bounds_of_rotations(x,c):
    """ Time complexity of this method is O(n^2) since we are going through a list of size n for n times. 
    """
    upper_bound = ''
    lower_bound = ''
    
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        value = 0
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
            index = (i+j) % len(x)
            value += x[index] * c**j
            
        if i == 0 or value > upper_bound:
            upper_bound = value
        if i == 0 or value < lower_bound:
            lower_bound = value
    
    return (lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

Comment: What language? And first tag `list` does not fit question

Comment: @Justinas Apologies, amended. I tried to use Python but feel free to use another language.

Comment: @Justinas Here's my approach. I think the way I'm approaching the problem is wrong, but yet I couldn't really come up with anything else.

Comment: Note that you can compute the values of `c^j` once, then calculate the dot product of two vectors.  Then, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744094/time-and-space-complexity-of-vector-dot-product-computation.

Comment: Are you sure that O(n) is needed? Perhaps O(nlogn) approach with correlation

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think I have a better idea now. Thanks! So maybe one approach would be to iteratively pop index 0 and attach it to the back for n times, n =len(x). Then each time, calculate the dot product x @ b, where b are the weight coefficients.

Comment: But then again, no never mind. Dot product is O(n) itself, so if I were to use a for loop for dot products in each iteration, its still O(n*n).

Comment: Is O(n) possible? In the computations I see 16 distinct values resulting from [2, 5, 6, 8] and 0.8 within the computation. Btw to compute the values using accelerated libraries, you can use `scipy` to create the `circulant` matrix of the `[2, 5, 6, 8]` vector and multiply with `numpy.power(0.8, range(4)).T` and get min and max of the result.

Comment: @MYousefi Thanks for the info and help. Frankly speaking, I am not sure myself, it was a 'bonus question' asking if it can be done with O(n) time complexity. It could be a simple "no", or mathematically there could be ways to pinpoint the best rotation, like by calculating the difference between the adjacent numbers.

I shall update here once I know the answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a O(n) algorithm effectively.
The idea is to build an array of size `2*n - 1`:

```
{1*X[0] C*X[1] C^2*X[2] ... C^n-1*X[n-1] C^n*X[0] C^n+1*X[1] ... C^(2*n-2)* X[n-2]}
```

and to perform on it a sliding window sum calculation, wich can be implemented in O(2*n) = O(n).

The expected dot products are equal to the running sums, up to a weighting factor `C^k`.

Here is a simple C++ implementation, that could be easily transposed in any language.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

std::pair<double, double> min_max_rotation (const std::vector<int>& X, double C) {
    int n = X.size();
    double vmin = 0.0, vmax = 0.0;
    double coef = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    std::vector<double> Xweighted (2*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Xweighted[i] = X[i] * coef;
        sum += Xweighted[i];
        coef *= C;
    }
    vmin = vmax = sum;
    double factor = C;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        Xweighted[i+n] = X[i] * coef;
        coef *= C;
        sum += (Xweighted[i+n] - Xweighted[i]);
        double dot_product = sum / factor;
        factor *= C;
        if (dot_product < vmin) vmin = dot_product;
        if (dot_product > vmax) vmax = dot_product;
    }
    return {vmin, vmax};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> X = {2, 5, 6, 8};
    double C = 0.8;
    auto [vmin, vmax] = min_max_rotation (X, C);
    std::cout << vmin << "   " << vmax << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice method of dot_product updating at every step!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Someone else shared with me a similar solution: First calculate the sum of the first rotation. Then for every step of the sliding window, subtract value of the first integer, divide by c to "bring everything forward by one index" in one step, and add the value of the removed integer with the appropriate weights back.